# How To Dynamically Map Array to Query Params

Tags: reactjs, query-string

My goal is to map an array of selected values to a query param, which will return the columns that I need.

I get the values to pass in my query, but they're not formatted for correctly.  These values can range from 1-4 values of animal columns.

`?columns=DOG,CAT,TURTLE,FISH&`

Should be:

`?columns=DOG&columns=CAT&columns=TURTLE&columns=FISH`

My try for sending the URL query:

```
try {
    const { data } = fetchContext.authAxios.get(`/api/csv/pet/${id}/${
        values.columns ? `?columns=${values.columns}&columns=/` : ''
      }`,
    values
  );
}
```

How can I properly loop through these values in the format needed?  Or is there a React package for this?

Comment: the variable values is filled with that data { columns: ["FISH", "DOG","CAT","TURTLE"] }?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a String before you make the API call. Something like:

```dart
List<String> list = ["DOG", "CAT", "TURTLE", "FISH"];

String queryParam = "?";

for (String str in list) {
  queryParam += "columns=${str}&"
}

try {
    const { data } = fetchContext.authAxios.get(`/api/csv/pet/${id}/${
        values.columns ? `${queryParam}columns=/` : ''
      }`,
    values
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you reformat your answer into JS and not TS?  Having trouble understanding the `List<String>` portion.

Comment: I used the [flutter] tag, still I saw your question. The syntax I wrote is in dart. The helpful part that can be useful that how I built the String in the `for` cycle. Then just build the URL in another variable like this: `const url = `/api/csv/pet/${id}/${values.columns ? queryParam+`columns=/` : ''}``  I am not really a JS guy, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I was using the wrong approach and needed to structure the API call and pass it to axios with this [snippet on gist.github](https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743).